# Changing contents of an xul element

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have just started developing a firefox addon. I want to change the contents of a label as follows:

```xml
  <label id = "current_feed">
   "The commentary will appear here."
  </label>
```

I want to change "The commentary will appear here." text using javascript. I tried 
`document.getElementById( "current_feed").innerHTML  = array[0];`, but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate. From what you've provided, I cannot tell what the problem is. Where is `array` being declared?

Comment: array is declared and populated(correctly) in the same method.

Comment: @user1016313: You should avoid using `innerHTML` if possible, especially if `array[0]` contains downloaded HTML content as I suspect it does. See [Displaying web content in an extension without security issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Displaying_web_content_in_an_extension_without_security_issues).

Answer (score -1):

This would work if `array` were being declared properly. Please view this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fAwGf/).

Comment: Yes. Just keep in mind that `innerHTML` **replaces** the contents of an element. Therefore, if you want to make an `input` a child of the `label` then you would need to include that, as well.